# Finding unique file names from an html file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, grep

```
$ cat downloaded_file.html

1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON11202010_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
```

How do I search an html file from my shell script and select the unique filenames those start with `STDMON` and end with `_company.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only digits between `STDMON` and `_company.txt` you can do:

```
grep -o 'STDMON[0-9]*_company\.txt' input.txt | sort -u
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/chutG)

And if there can be anything you can do:

```
grep -oP 'STDMON.*?_company\.txt' input.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -F'>|<' '$3 ~ /STDMON[0-9]+_company.txt/ && !a[$0=$3]++' download_file.html
```

#### Input

```
$ cat downloaded_file.html
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON11202010_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON11202010_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON14959440_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON11202010_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON14959440_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON11202010_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
1373 <A HREF="http://site.com/STDMON11202010_company.txt">STDMON12342440_company.txt</A><br> Monday, November 22, 2010  1:31 AM
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -F'>|<' '$3 ~ /STDMON[0-9]+_company.txt/ && !a[$0=$3]++'
STDMON11202010_company.txt
STDMON14959440_company.txt
STDMON12342440_company.txt
```